# How to hide show UIButton text not button in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Lcc.png)I am facing a problem in iOS swift. I am trying to hide and show the `UIButton` text that is added in the `UITextview` list. I want to hide the button text on click and show on re-click the button. I can't keep nil the button text because i give the background colour to the button according to the alphabet.

[[image]]

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

My problem is not solved

Comment: Post you inputs here too rather than text only.

Comment: please post code snippets and what you have implemented so people will understand your problem and know how to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying that you can't nil the button's text, you should do this,

You can implement this Bool extension also,

```
extension Bool {
    mutating func toggle() {
        self = !self
    }
}


@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.titleLabel?.isHidden.toggle()
}
```

this will show and hide your Button's `titleLabel` text.

**UPDATE**

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected.toggle()
    if sender.isSelected == true {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.clear, for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: not work for me

Comment: @Softlabsindia what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: i only want to hide and show the button label  on click

Comment: @Softlabsindia is it working for you? let me know in case of any queries

Answer (score 2):

1. Setting your button title color in state normal and selected state
2. When click to button, just simple change the state.

// Settings

```
// let button = <your button>
button.setTitleColor(<yourColor>, for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.clear, for: .selected)
```

// Action

```
@IBAction func didSelectButton(_ button: UIButton) {
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentTitle = "" {
        sender.setTitle("myTitle", for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: no need this method

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myButton.setTitle("myTitle", for: .normal)
    myButton.setTitle("", for: .selected)
}

@IBAction func myButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    myButton.isSelected = !myButton.isSelected
}
```

Comment: Its a duplicate